# how to use individual component from an API by calling dynamically in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I implement a project where i have to call API. From this API [enter link description here](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all)  first i show 250 countries and then create a details component where show all details individually by clicking a button or link.  But i faced some problem. Since i have a little knowledge about react and API so i didn't understand how to call API for individually show country details in my details component. I need help because i want to know that how can I dynamically call single country from 250 countries API

[image]
----------This is the component here i load all countries by calling rest API. After that i couldn't call any single country

[image]
This is my country details component where i want to load individual country details

[image]
After getting some help i understand that api is coming in useState but i can not implement

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
const CountryDetails = () => {
const {countryName} = useParams();
const [country,setCountry] = useState([]);  //use object
console.log(countryName);
console.log(country[0]);
useEffect(()=>{
    // const url = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`;
    const url = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${countryName}`;
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setCountry(data));
},[countryName])
// console.log(country);
return (
    <div>
        <h3>This is  {countryName}</h3>
        {/* <h2>{country[0]}</h2> */}
        <h4>{countryName.capital}</h4>
    </div>
); }; export default CountryDetails;
```

this is App.js in my project

```
import './App.css';
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Switch,
Route,
Link,
useParams,
useRouteMatch 
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Components/Home/Home';
import CountryDetails from './Components/CountryDetails/CountryDetails';
import NotFound from './Components/NotFound/NotFound';
function App() {
return (
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/home">
      <Home/>

    </Route>
    <Route path="/:countryName">
      <CountryDetails></CountryDetails>
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path="*">
      <NotFound></NotFound>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
 </Router>
 );
 }  export default App;
```

I need to implement this component for showing individual country details

Comment: If you are wanting to show the details for a specific country ***and*** you are using react-router you can create a generic country details page and place it on a dynamic route and pass the country details data in route state. Can you provide an example code snippet of your main app component rendering the entire list of countries and your router & routes?

Comment: NM, looks like you have a route for it, and it seems the rest API url is correct. What is the issue?

Comment: i can't implement all details in details component

Comment: You mean you can not show all the data inside a country object to the view ?

Comment: right. Actually i don't know how to show all the data

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with how you attempt to render the details. The country data will still be in array format. `countryName` is the string route parameter, so it won't have any country specific properties to call.

```
<div>
    <h3>This is  {countryName}</h3>
    {/* <h2>{country[0]}</h2> */}
    <h4>{countryName.capital}</h4> // <-- countryName is string!!
</div>
```

You can simply map the country results similarly to how it was done on the main page. Destructure the detail values you want to use for rendering the details.

```
return country.map(({ capital, name }) => ( // <-- destructure all values needed
  <div key={name} className="country">
    <h3>
      Country Name: {name}
    </h3>
    <div>
      Capital: {capital}
    </div>
    <button type="button" onClick={history.goBack}>Back</button>
  </div>
))
```

[image]

[image: Edit how-to-use-individual-component-from-an-api-by-calling-dynamically-in-react]

Full Demo Code:

Home page

```
const Home = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setCountries(data));
  }, []);

  const history = useHistory();

  return countries.map(({ capital, name }) => (
    <div key={name} className="country">
      <div>Country Name: {name}</div>
      <div>Capital: {capital}</div>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() =>
          history.push({
            pathname: `/${name}`
          })
        }
      >
        Details
      </button>
    </div>
  ));
};
```

Details page

```
const CountryDetails = () => {
  const { countryName } = useParams();

  const [country, setCountry] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${countryName}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setCountry(data));
  }, [countryName]);

  const history = useHistory();

  return country.map(
    ({ capital, flag, name, nativeName, population, region, subregion }) => (
      <div key={name} className="country">
        <h3>Country Name: {name}</h3>
        <img
          src={flag}
          alt="flag"
          style={{
            height: "100px"
          }}
        />
        <div>Capital: {capital}</div>
        <div>Region: {region}</div>
        <div>Subregion: {subregion}</div>
        <div>Population: {population}</div>
        <div>Native Name: {nativeName}</div>
        <button type="button" onClick={history.goBack}>
          Back
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  );
};
```

App

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/:countryName">
            <CountryDetails />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it's so helpful for me <3

Comment: On more question how to show flag on your code?

Comment: ok. It's really helpful for me and again thanks a lot

Comment: well is there any way to use subarray from the api. For instance "currencies":[{"code":"BDT","name":"Bangladeshi taka","symbol":"৳"}] if i want to use just symbol then what should i need to do?

Comment: @Raifur-rahim Sure. Destructure `currencies` and map what you need, something like `currencies.map(({ symbol }) => symbol).join(", ")`. I updated codesandbox. Antarctica was the first entry I found with multiple currencies.

Comment: how can i implement borders component just try your link like this <div>borders: {borders.map(({}) => borders).join(", ")}</div> but it shows repeat all

Comment: another question is how can i use multiple value in currencies ?

Comment: @Raifur-rahim The borders is interesting since it appears to use the `alpha3Code` property of the bordering countries. If you simply want to list the codes, then it's as simple as `borders.join(", ")` since it is already an array of strings, there aren't any properties to access. (I updated sandbox code) If you would rather display a name then you can either make further calls to `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/{code}` for each code and access the `name` property.

Comment: @Raifur-rahim At this point I should point out that it would be better to simply store the first request in state and just pass data around. If you store the countries data in a React Context you can simply query against that for details versus more network requests. Also, can you clarify what you mean by "use multiple value in currencies"?

Answer (score -1):

You are making a mistake when accessing the data in CountryDetails component.

Instead of this

```
<h4>{countryName.capital}</h4>
```

Do this

```
<h4>{country[0].capital}</h4>
```

Comment: i already used this but it's not appropriate for all because i have to show all country details by dynamically . If i use this then it not work for all

Comment: the question isn't really that clear, to understand exactly what you want. If i understand correctly you want to show all properties of a single country dynamically in country details component. Is that correct?